# Table valued Function - Identity(seed, increment)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table Valued Function `qlikview_verlauf`. I want to return a table with `id`, `Date` and `Path`.

```
Identity(seed, increment)
```

The ID is an autoincrement value. I want to start this autoincrement (seed) from the `max(id)+1` from another table named `Testfortschritt`.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work. The Error Message is incorrect Syntax.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[qlikview_verlauf](@param INT)
    RETURNS @qlikview_verlauf table (
           ID INT IDENTITY((Select max(id) from Testfortschritt),1) 
          ,[Date] date NOT NULL
          ,[Path] varchar(600) NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: Could you describe full scenario? What for do you need ids related to real table column values?

Answer (score 1):

I would set aside the `IDENTITY` of your ID column and rather use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the ID in your `SELECT` statement.

For example:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Testfortschritt) +
      ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID,
   [Date],
   [Path]
FROM <YourTable>
```

Since I don't know how your exact statement looks like, I used `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` which lets SQL Server decide in which order records are numbered. If you have a specific order just replace `(SELECT 1)` with your order columns.

Since the ID should be uniqe I also omitted the `PARTITION BY` clause which isn't needed in your scenario.

More about `ROW_NUMBER` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms186734.aspx)